# Try to push notification

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to push notification , but get this error "Failed: TooManyProviderTokenUpdate" , How to fix it ? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBFQ9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're updating the provider token too often. From [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/handling_notification_responses_from_apns):

> The provider’s authentication token is being updated too often. Update the authentication token no more than once every 20 minutes.